# How do I upload an image file in my GIT Repository using browser?

Tags: git, github

Hi I am new to Github.

I want to upload a jpg file in my GIT repository. Is it possible using broswer ? how ?
If not, is it possible using command line ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

```
git add [imageFileName]
git commit
git push # if you have remote repository, not local
```

It may be possible using browser, but you have to be more specific - you mean internet browser? Or some GUI over git?

Comment: Then it depends on where your repositiory is hosted. But most of the time (maybe always) - the answer is no. You need to have a local copy of repository on your local machine, add files there, then commit and push to make them visible on remote repo

Comment: You can also use some git GUI - like TortoiseGit. These would execute commands for you without typing them manually

Answer (score 0):

In the command line:

```
git add path_here/image_name.extension
```

Just put the path there, then commit and push

```
git commit -m 'commit message here'
git push origin master
```

This is assuming you have a git repository already initialized in your working directory.

If you haven't, then navigate to your working directory and type:

```
git init
```

Then type the first three lines in order.